# File explorer defaulting to view as list except if mostly images, then as thumbs

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

is anyone aware of a windows and/or linux file explorer who allows to choose to view folders as lists of items with minimal graphical clutter, except when most of the folder is composed of images, in which case it would default to thumbnail view?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Open Folder Properties – Customize tab – Optimize this folder for, each type has its corresponding view layout.

You can have an identification:
1.  In general, add a new folder, it’s default “Optimize this folder for” option is configured as “General items”. And its corresponding view layout is Details.
2.  Change the  “Optimize this folder for” option to “Pictures”, save the change, then, view layout will be changed to “Medium icons”.

(above are tests on my Windows 10)

Comment: This is folder by folder. I'm specifically looking for a default behaviour.